# Embed this externally made form into my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this website where I want to add a form which opens once you press the login button. The form was created using an online form builder which provides an embed code for embedding into your website. I have provided the embed code along with the html/css for my website.

The **HTML**:

```
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Help</a>
  </div>

<!-- <div id="main">
    <span class="openbutton" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  </div>
-->
  <div class="header">
      <span class="openbutton" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
      <div class="header-right">
          <a class="active" href="#home">Login</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
  }
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .3s;
    padding: 20px;
}


* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    padding: 25px 20px;
}

.header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}



.header a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.header a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
}
```

embed code for the form:

```
    <a name="form691431825" id="formAnchor691431825"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fs3.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?691431825"></script><script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({    
key: "https://fs3.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=iGs2D6QRb6IgzQCoK79H%2B6%2F3bsAv%2BgQi&691431825",
    width: "100%",  
mobileResponsive: true
});</script>
```

Comment: Did you try just copying that embed code into your HTML at that position where it show appear?

Comment: @HerrSerkerI hve tried embedding it in a normal way in which when the page loads the form is on the front of the page. But what i want is to embed the form under the login button.

Comment: wrap the embed code in a div which is hidden by default. After click on the button, unhide the div

Comment: @HerrSerker alright but could you please elaborate on what to do exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to rephrase the text of your post as you only make remarks without asking any question, having people to guess what it is you need.

Assuming you need a trigger to open your login window, here's what I did to make it work:

Modify the script with `EmbedManager.embed(..);` and put it inside a function called `openLogin()`

```
  function openLogin() {
    EmbedManager.embed({    
        key: "https://fs3.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=iGs2D6QRb6IgzQCoK79H%2B6%2F3bsAv%2BgQi&691431825",
        width: "100%",  
        mobileResponsive: true
        });
    }
```

Now you have a javascript function you can use to open your login screen. Once you have choosen an element (a,button,div,etc) you want to use as the trigger add properties`name="form691431825" id="formAnchor691431825" onclick="javascript:openLogin()"`, remove the original a-element and your are good to go.

The result does not look too pretty, leaving you with the next fun puzzle to chew on...